# aria-label attribute not being read when navigating using keyboard

Tags: javascript, html, accessibility, wai-aria

```
<span class="phone" aria-label="phone number 9 4 9 . 5 5 5 . 1 2 3 4">949.555.1234</span>
```

This prints out the phone number on the page. clicking on the phone number will read the aria-label as expected, however, if I navigate to the phone number using the keyboard arrow it reads whatever text is outputted on the page ("nine hundred forty-nine period five hundred"...) in this case and the aria-label is not respected.

using ChromeVox

Also it might be worth mentioning that, the span tag doesn't recieve focus when using the arrow keys. i.e. `$("span").focus(function(){ // never gets here })`

Comment: This doesn't seem to be a question. If you want to report a bug to the developers of ChromeVox then see http://www.chromevox.com/feedback.html

Comment: ah, didn't realize this could be chromeVox issue, thought it might be a general one. Just used a different one and I don't see the issue. Thanks!

Comment: `<a href="tel:9495551234" aria-label="949. 5 5 5. 1 2 3 4.">(949) 555-1234</a>` try this way.  Note the spaces and periods in the label. The spaces in the label tell the screen reader to read each digit individually. The period after the area code and the exchange tell the screen reader to pause

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Can you clarify what you mean by "navigating using the keyboard"?

Are you using <kbd>TAB</kbd> to get to the phone number and then the screen reader doesn't read your `aria-label`?  (You don't have `tabindex="0"` on your `<span>` so I'm guessing that you are **not** using the <kbd>TAB</kbd> key.)

Or are you navigating with the keyboard using screen reader keys, such as the up/down keys that walk the DOM (or more accurately, walk the accessibility tree, which is similar to the DOM).

If doing the latter, then many browsers will **not** surface the `aria-label` of an element in the accessibility tree if that element doesn't have a [role](https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria-1.1/#role_definitions).  `<span>` elements don't have any semantic meaning so you'd have to add the `role` attribute as well.  Whether this is correct behavior is debatable, since the [`aria-label` spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria/#aria-label) doesn't specifically say a role must also be specified.

There are some [ARIA guidelines](https://www.w3.org/TR/using-aria/#label-support) on how the `aria-label` is supported that explains (sort of) why the `aria-label` might be ignored on a `<span>`.

So if you really want the `aria-label` read, you'll have to decide what kind of role to give the `<span>`.  It's hard to tell with just your small snippet of code but is the phone number part of other information as well, such as a name and address?  If so, is the other info (name, address, etc) displayed in a list or table, or is it just plain text?

However, as a side note, when you specify an `aria-label` for the purpose of forcing a screen reader to read text a certain way, that's usually **not** a recommended practice.  Hearing a phone number read as a real number instead of as single digits is certainly not ideal for a screen reader user, but they're used to it and can navigate numbers a digit at a time if they so choose.  At some point, when the `autocomplete` attribute is more widely supported by screen readers, then hopefully this problem will be resolved.  In the meantime, when you force text for a screen reader, it can have detrimental affects for braille users.  In your phone example, as a braille user, my braille device will show me "nine space four space nine space dot space five space five space five space [etc]".  That's a lot of braille characters for the space character that I have to weed through.

Comment: I bookmarked this earlier, intending to answer it myself, but yours has it covered.  There's a good summary in [Short note on aria-label, aria-labelledby, and aria-describedby](https://developer.paciellogroup.com/blog/2017/07/short-note-on-aria-label-aria-labelledby-and-aria-describedby/) too.

Comment: Yes, I like Léonie's blogs.  She's well-respected in the accessibility community.  Her blog, in this case, is just a summary of the "ARIA Guidelines" link mentioned earlier.  The guidelines were pretty short to begin with (just 10 bullet points) and Léonie made it 4 bullet points.